# Typescript exist namespace with reserved word

Tags: node.js, typescript, paypal, typescript-typings, paypal-rest-sdk

I want to upgrade ["paypal-rest-sdk" typings](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/paypal-rest-sdk). This SDK has method `payment.authorization.void(...)`;

`void` method doesn't exist on `@types/paypal-rest-sdk`, and I am trying to override it by local declarations.

Code example:

```
declare module "paypal-rest-sdk" {
  export namespace authorization {
    function void(): any;
  }
}

export const paypal = Paypal;
```

But this code doesn't work, and when I try to call `void` method, typescript shows me an error: `Error:(94, 49) TS2339: Property 'void' does not exist on type 'typeof authorization'.`

Answer (score 2):

The only way I can see to provide a type definition that includes a method named `void` (sigh) is using a variable rather than a namespace.

Here is an example based on the current definition on Definitely Typed (but with the `authorization` namespace converted to a variable).

```
export var authorization: {
    get: (
        id: string,
        config: http.RequestOptions | CallbackFunction<AuthorizationResource>,
        cb?: CallbackFunction<AuthorizationResource>) => void;
    capture: (
        id: string,
        data: CaptureRequest | http.RequestOptions | CallbackFunction<CaptureResource>,
        config?: http.RequestOptions | CallbackFunction<CaptureResource>,
        cb?: CallbackFunction<CaptureResource>) => void;
    reauthorize: (
        id: string, data: Amount | http.RequestOptions | CallbackFunction<AuthorizationResource>,
        config?: http.RequestOptions | CallbackFunction<AuthorizationResource>,
        cb?: CallbackFunction<AuthorizationResource>) => void;
    void: (data?: any, config?: http.RequestOptions, cb?: CallbackFunction<any>) => void;
}
```

Specific changes:

- `export namespace authorization` changed to `export var authorization`
- namespace body converted to type annotation
- each `export function` converted to member
- each function converted to type annotation

This can be accessed without type errors:

```
...authorization.void(data, config, callback);
```