# Use a reserved keyword as a property in a typescript interface

Tags: typescript, reserved-words

I’d like to define a typescript `interface` to map answers from a web service to a type (similar to what is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13320802/)). Here is an example answer.

```
{
    "type": "Seen",
    "creation": 33,
    "fileId": 6
}
```

Hence the following interface would be suitable.

```
interface Event {
    type: 'Accepted' | 'Judgment' | 'Seen';
    creation: number;
    fileId: number;
}
```

Unfortunately, the compiler does not like it: `type` is a reserved keyword.

How can I use a reserved keyword as a property inside an interface?

I guess it is possible to define the property using another term and then define an alias to it somehow, as suggested [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26995#issuecomment-420434612), or use `var` instead as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48994384/), but I can’t find out how to do it in my case.

Comment: You extending the ambient `Event` type (from `lib.dom.d.ts`) rather than creating an independent `Event` type. Just rename your type to something unique (e.g. `ReviewEvent`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is perfectly fine to use properties called `type` in an `interface`. In fact, you can use all keywords of TypeScript in interfaces:

```js
interface Test {
  type: string
  class: string
  any: string
}
```

The problem here is that you are modifying an **existing** `interface` which already defines `type` to be of type `string`:

```js
// lib.dom.d.ts
/** An event which takes place in the DOM. */
interface Event {
  readonly type: string;
  /* ... */
}
```

You can define multiple interfaces with the same name to merge them. This is called "[Declaration Merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html)". But if you define the same properties with different types you get the following error:

> All declarations of 'type' must have identical modifiers.

---

So unless you are trying to modify the globally available interface `Event`, you should just choose another name of the interface.